# How to schedule runbook based on minutes in Azure automation Account

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook, azure-scheduler

How to schedule automatically execute runbooks based on minutes instead of hours in Microsoft azure automation account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm, I thought this was possible, but it appears not. you can create multiple hourly schedules for this (if you want it to start every 10 minutes - create 6 hourly schedules), you can create an azure function timer triggered and just start your runbook with that (more hacky, I guess) or create an external event that would start the runbook using the Azure API or, perhaps, via a webhook

Comment: I think this is the only option we can do run the scheduler based on minutes

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you have to create 60 schedules 1 for each minute to reoccur every hour.
Luckily Powershell is here to help:

```
$AutomationAccountName = ""
$ResourceGroupName = ""
$Subscription = ""
$tenant = ""
$runbookName = ""

Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $tenant -Subscription $Subscription

$i = 0
While($i -le 59){
    $StartTime = Get-Date "16:$($i):00"
    $Name = "EveryMinute $($i)"
    $i++

    $schedule = New-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName -Name $Name -StartTime $StartTime -HourInterval 1 -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName 
    $Register = Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName -Name $runbookName -ScheduleName $Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
}
```